# H a subgroup of index n, then G has a normal subgroup K with [G : K] ≤ n!.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that if G is a group and H a subgroup of index n, then G has a normal subgroup K with [G : K] ≤ n!

I'm having trouble proving this because frankly I have no idea where to start. Any tips?

Comment: There is a natural group homomorphism $G\to \text{Perm}(G/H)$, where $\text{Perm}(G/H)$ is the group of permutations on the set of cosets $G/H$.

Comment: Related: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1662203/11619),[2](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/844522/11619). Use *core* as a buzzword to search for more within our tag [tag:group-theory].

Answer (score 4):

Start by considering the action of $G$ on the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$. From this we get a homomorphism (the associated permutation representation), whose kernel $K$ is normal and contained in $H$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the homomorphism from G -> G/N? And why is K normal and in H?

Comment: Yeah, thats the same homomorphism I was referring to. The kernel of any homomorphism is always normal, to see this note that a subgroup $N$ is normal iff $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$ for all $g \in G$, use this to show that the kernel of any homomorphism is normal. You actually don't need to use the fact that $K$ is contained in $H$ for the result you are trying to prove.